# Using pppoeconf dsl connection not connecting after connection drop [16.04 lt]

Tags: networking, internet

I am a beginner user on Linux. I have a wired connection and using "`pppoeconf`" I can connect to the Internet easily but if somehow connection is dropped then I have to restart my computer to make connection work again.

As you can see, I can't torrent properly and I feel insecure every time I go outside leaving my computer ON and connection may drop again.